# Framer motion drag: set drag target as child of draggable parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm trying to set up a component using Framer Motion which has a draggable div, but the drag target (element which is draggable) is a child of the draggable parent div. Similar to OS windows only being draggable by the top menu bar. I've fiddled with dragControls but I don't know if this is my answer. If I set the motion.div to the child div, only it moves.

```
         <motion.div drag > // This entire div should move when the target is dragged
            <div> // I only want this div to be the draggable target
                <span>DRAG ME</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>This div should move with the parent draggable div, but you can not drag from this div.</p>
            </div>
        </motion.div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution, using `dragListener` prop (not very well documented tho):

```
import {motion, useDragControls} from 'framer-motion'

export function Example() {
  const dragControls = useDragControls()

  return (
    <motion.div
      drag
      dragControls={dragControls}
      dragListener={false}
    >
      <div
        onPointerDown={(e) => {
          dragControls.start(e)
        }}
      >
        <span>DRAG ME</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>
          This div should move with the parent draggable div, but you can not drag from this div.
        </p>
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  )
}
```

Here a codesandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-dawn-p4whg?file=/src/App.tsx:0-617

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way of doing this at the moment.
This little "hack" might be the only way: (You were right, dragControls will be needed)

```
import { motion, useDragControls } from "framer-motion";

export const Example = () => {
  const dragControls = useDragControls();

  function onDragStart(e, info) {
    // We will ignore the request to drag if it's not coming from the handle
    if (!e.target.classList.contains( 'drag-handle' ) ) {
    
      // Stop the drag - `e` and `info` are needed from the library
      dragControls.componentControls.forEach( entry => {
        entry.stop( e, info )
      })
    }
  }

return (
  // Add dragControls and onDragStart to the div you want to be draggable
  <motion.div
    drag
    dragControls={dragControls}
    onDragStart={onDragStart}
  >
    <div>
      {* Add a descriptive class to the element that enables the dragging *}
      <span className="drag-handle">DRAG ME</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>This div should move with the parent draggable div, but you can not drag from 
      this div.</p>
    </div>
  </motion.div>
)
```

}